# Prove that in the ring $F[t,t^{-1}]$ we have $x=t^n \Leftrightarrow x \mid 1$ and $t-1 \mid x-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra

I want to prove the following lemma:

> For any $x$ in the ring $F[t,t^{-1}]$ ($F[t,t^{-1}]$: the polynomials in $t$ and $t^{-1}$ with coefficients in the field $F$), $x$ is a power of $t$ if and only if $x$ divides $1$ and $t-1$ divides $x-1$ (the divisibilities are meant, of course, in $F[t, t^{-1}]$).

I have done the following:

$\Rightarrow $ :

$x=t^n$

$x-1=t^n-1=(t-1)(t^{n-1}+ \cdots +1) \Rightarrow t-1 \mid x-1$

But how can we conclude that $x \mid 1$ ?

$\Leftarrow $ :

$x \mid 1 \ \ \ \ \& \ \ \ \ t-1 \mid x-1$

$x \mid 1 \Rightarrow x=\pm 1$

$x-1 = k(t-1)$

But how can we conclude that $x=t^n$ ?

Comment: What does $F[t,t^{-1}]$ mean?

Comment: $F[t,t^{-1}]$ : (ring) the polynomials in $t$ and $t^{-1}$ with coefficients in the field $F$. @Khallil

Comment: $x \vert 1$ does not imply $x = \pm 1$, e.g. $t^{-1} \vert 1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> $x\in F[t,t^{-1}]$ is a power of $t$ iff $x$ is invertible (or, equivalently $x\mid 1$) and $t-1\mid x-1$.

If $x=t^n$, then $xt^{-n}=1$, and as you already noticed $t-1\mid t^n-1$.

For the converse write $x=f(t)/t^n$ with $n\ge0$ and $f(t)\in F[t]$. Since $x$ is invertible there exists $y\in F[t,t^{-1}]$ such that $xy=1$. Write $y=g(t)/t^m$ with $m\ge0$ and $g(t)\in F[t]$. From $xy=1$ we get $f(t)g(t)=t^{m+n}$. It follows that $f(t)=at^i$ with $a\in F^\times$ and $i\ge0$, so $x=at^{r}$. But $t-1\mid x-1$, that is, $t-1\mid at^r-1=a(t^r-1)+a-1$, so $a=1$.

Comment: Could you explain to me why $x$ can be written as $x=f(t)/t^n$ and $y$ as $y=g(t)/t^m$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar An element $x\in F[t,t^{-1}]$ is a polynomial in $t$ and $t^{-1}$ as you said. Now write $x=a_{-u}t^{-u}+\cdots+a_{-1}t^{-1}+a_0+a_1t+\cdots a_vt^v$ with $u,v\ge0$, then multiply this by $t^u$ and obtain $xt^u=f(t)$ which is a polynomial from $F[t]$, so $x=f(t)/t^u$.

Comment: I see... Could you explain to me also the part "It follows that $f(t)=at^i$ with $a \in F^{\times}$ and $i \geq 0$, so $x=at^r$." Why is $f(t)$ this one? Why does it have only this term? Also I haven't really understood how we conclude that $a=1$...

Comment: @MaryStar in the polynomial ring $F[t]$, what kind of factors (besides units) can a polynomial $t^k$ have? To conclude $a = 1$, write the polynomial $at^r - 1$ in the form $q(t)(t-1) + r$, where $r \in F$.

Comment: In the polynomial ring $F[t]$ a polynomial $f(t)$ has the factorization $f(t)=g_1(t) g_2(t) \cdots g_k(t)$, where $g_i(t)$ are irreducible polynomials of $F[t]$, right? 
$$$$ 
Having that $x=at^r$ we do the following: $$t-1 \mid x-1 \Rightarrow t-1 \mid at^r-1 \\ \Rightarrow t-1 \mid at^r-a+a-1 \Rightarrow t-1 \mid a(t^r-1)+a-1 \\ \Rightarrow t-1 \mid a(t-1)(t^{r-1}+\cdots +t+1)+a-1$$ So, the remainder, $a-1$, must be zero, so $a=1$. Is this correct?  @DavidWheeler

Comment: Indeed. Since $F[t]$ is Euclidean, the remainder is unique.

Comment: $f(t)$ cannot be for example of the form $at^m+bt^n$, because then at the product $f(t)g(t)$ we wouldn't get the desired result, right? @DavidWheeler

Comment: $t^k = (t - 0)^k$, which clearly has only the linear factors $t-0 = t$. Any product of these factors (that is to say, any factor of $t^k$) is thus a power of $t$.

Comment: @MaryStar In $F[t]$ the element $t$ is prime. Then the divisors of powers of $t$ are also powers of $t$ eventually multiplied by an invertible element (for instance, in $\mathbb Z$ the divisors of $2^2$ are $\pm1$, $\pm2$, and $\pm2^2$), and that's why I've written $f(t)=at^i$ with $a\in F$, $a\ne0$ (the units of $F[t]$ are the non-zero elements of $F$).

Comment: Ok... Thank you very much!! :-)